# Swift frontend guide to make an application

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, textfield

i'am a junior developer of iOS and im currently still learning about making iOS app. And i have to make Application for my thesis and i wanna make an App like this but i just dont know what object from the library should i use to make this happen

i have a couple things that wanna ask, i just need to shown how to make that like if i have to search it on google or tutorial what keyword to look for.

so the first thing i wanna make something like this :

[image: i take this from Journey app for reference]

i wanna know how to add a full length of notes(i think it use textfield cause its a long notes) and how to add to the tableview, did i just have to make a variable of the notes so that variable can easily pass around the controller?

[image: The full description of the notes]

and for the second part is i didnt know how to edit the full description

i browse the web that it use uitableview for the first UI that i showed and i just have to make a section for each day the notes is make, but what im trying to understand is how to edit the full description of the notes. like this

[image: Edit part]

im planning to use firebase to store all of this notes and data, but i know that part but what i didnt know is how to make the frontend to work with what i want.

i know im kinda asking alot of question but i just need a pin point direction of where i should go and it dont need a code (well if theres a code it will be helpful)but i just asking for a direction cause im lost of how to make such a thing, cheers all :).

*i use Journey apps for reference and i hope i didnt do any copyrights.

Comment: If you are using UIKit you're going to need a few things — Navigation Controller (along with navigation bar buttons), Tab Bar controller,  a textfield for the main text area and a tableview for the table. This is a fairly simple app to make.

Comment: ahhh okay okay thanks for the tip sir

Answer (score 0):

In the begining you have to decide whiche method that you are choose to develop app UIs. Either Storyboards or programatically.
then you can dive in to components.

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Scren 2,3]

Comment: ahhhh i see thanks for the tip!!!, i probably gonna use storyboard cause so far thats what  i learn how to make it, but thank you very much cause i think it use uitableview not collection view so thank you sir, i just gonna have to figure it out how to edit and input a text into textview